# Organizing a String based on maxlength of each field

Tags: java, string

I've made a program that makes my life easier by reading a class and creating methods like these below:

```
//Ferramentas Parâmetros 
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Pesquisa", "ppaParametrosList", null, TipoAcessoBean.TELA));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Gravar", "ppaParametrosHome", "persist", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Atualizar Dados", "ppaParametrosHome", "update", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Leitura", "ppaParametrosHome", "find", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Excluir", "ppaParametrosHome", "remove", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
```

Don't worry about the language. It won't make it harder to understand what I need to make.
I want to organize it to be shown like this:

```
//Ferramentas Parâmetros 
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Pesquisa"       , "ppaParametrosList", null     , TipoAcessoBean.TELA));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Gravar"         , "ppaParametrosHome", "persist", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Atualizar Dados", "ppaParametrosHome", "update" , TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Leitura"        , "ppaParametrosHome", "find"   , TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
acessos.add(new AcessoBean("Ferramentas", "Parâmetros", "Parâmetros", "Excluir"        , "ppaParametrosHome", "remove" , TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));
```

I'm reading the whole class with Scanner, but once I read, I save only the things I want in a Collection containing this things above. How can I make a method to complete with blank to make it organized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tabularize {

    static String input =
        "acessos.add(new AcessoBean(\"Ferramentas\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Pesquisa\", \"ppaParametrosList\", null, TipoAcessoBean.TELA));\n" + 
        "acessos.add(new AcessoBean(\"Ferramentas\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Gravar\", \"ppaParametrosHome\", \"persist\", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));\n" + 
        "acessos.add(new AcessoBean(\"Ferramentas\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Atualizar Dados\", \"ppaParametrosHome\", \"update\", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));\n" + 
        "acessos.add(new AcessoBean(\"Ferramentas\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Leitura\", \"ppaParametrosHome\", \"find\", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));\n" + 
        "acessos.add(new AcessoBean(\"Ferramentas\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Parâmetros\", \"Excluir\", \"ppaParametrosHome\", \"remove\", TipoAcessoBean.ACAO));";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        int[] maxWidth = new int[1024];

        String[] lines = input.split( "\n" );
        List<String[]> output = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for( String line : lines ) {
            String[] columns = line.split( "\\s*,\\s*" );
            output.add( columns );

            int i = 0;
            for( String column : columns ) {
                maxWidth[i] = Math.max( maxWidth[i], column.length() );
                i ++;
            }
        }

        for( String[] columns : output ) {
            int i = 0;
            String delim = "";
            for( String column : columns ) {
                System.out.print( delim );
                delim = ", ";

                String format = String.format("%%-%ds", maxWidth[i]);
                System.out.printf( format, column );

                i ++;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to store the result in a String?

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the values by commas.
2. Find the longest string in all rows
   for each column.
3. Rebuild the text adding space after
   each value so that the total length
   is equal to the longest value in the
   column.

Comment: ya, i know i'll have to do it, but it's freezing my thoughts when i'm trying to do it. like, using collection<string> or collection<string[]> or anything else?

Comment: Sorry, but your question was how to do it, so I listed a rough algorithm.  If you could be more specific with what part you are struggling with that would help.  As far as Collection<String> vs Collection<String[]>.   The second case is 2D which would be more suited for what you are doing.